# Select a Node in a TreeView with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, treeview

I have a `TreeView` within a `UserForm` in Excel.
When a Node is selected from the `TreeView`, a `ListBox` is populated with data.
When an item in the `ListBox` is double-clicked, a separate `UserForm` is shown which allows the user do to stuff.
Once the user returns back to the `TreeView UserForm`, I want the `Node` that was selected previously to be highlighted.

The problem is that the `UserForm` basically resets itself, and I can't figure out how to select a `Node` with VBA.

I'm at the point where I'm debating on whether or not I can just manually fire a `NodeClick` event, as everything else I've tried has failed.

Any tips?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but i had trouble enough finding a decent answer myself so here we go. Index or Key's are not always available. On create I place the fullpath of the node in the node.tag. On double-click I recall the tag value, later on I search the treeview node collection for the tag. To much? not efficient? maybe but its works likes a charm every time and i can use my own identifiers in the tag based on the purpose of the treeview. The find code:

```
Sub MyTreeview_FindNode(strKey As String)
Dim myNode As Node

   For Each myNode In Me.Treeview.Nodes
       If myNode.Tag = strKey Then
          myNode.Selected = True
          myNode.EnsureVisible
          End If
       Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

In my Excel works:

```
TreeView1.Nodes(key).Selected = True
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several options. First, when the TreeView UserForm displays the second UserForm, you either need to:

1. Save the ID of the selected node (use a form-level or module-level variable).  Then you need to write a method to select the node upon return to the form. IIRC, you need to have a unique 'Key' or ID for each node element and then use TreeView.Select for the node returned from TreeView.FindNode. -- or --
2. Hide the TreeView UserForm instead of closing it (Me.Hide). When the second UserForm is closed (or OK/Cancel pressed), then show the TreeView UserForm again (TreeViewForm.Show).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
objTreeview.Object.Nodes(KEY_NAME).Selected=TRUE

Where KEY_NAME is the key (string) that you used to create the node

Answer (score 0):

```
Set xTree = Me!tv_bom.Object
        
xTree.Nodes.Item(Index).Selected = True
```